# Keep a Frame in an other window Frame

Tags: python-2.7, window, wxpython, frame

My programm create a Frame with three panels in an horizontal boxsizer. A menu with "new window" item for create a seconde Frame. I  give the seconde panel as parent of the seconde window. I wante the seconde Frame stays in the seconde panel area of my first frame.
if user move one of the two windows, the seconde stays in the panel screen area.
Do you know a way or something for that?
I tried a little something, but using is not very aesthetic.

and

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Python Test App',size=(600,400))

        #Widgets
        panel_gch = wx.Panel(self,-1,size = (150,-1))
        panel_gch.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(300,400))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour((200,230,200))
        panel_drt = wx.Panel(self,-1,size = (150,-1))
        panel_drt.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(box)

        #Add
        box.Add(panel_gch,0,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(panel_drt,0,wx.EXPAND)

        #Menu
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu=wx.Menu()
        ID_FILE_NEW = 1
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_NEW,"New Window","This is a new window")
        menubar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        #bind and layout
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.get_new_window)
        panel_gch.Layout()
        self.panel.Layout()
        panel_drt.Layout()
        self.Layout()

    def get_new_window(self,event): # create new window
        self.new = NewWindow(self.panel,-1)
        self.new.Show(True)
        self.new.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE,self.window2_on_move)

    def window2_on_move(self,event): # Window2 must stay in
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        v,w =self.panel.GetScreenPosition()
        s,t = self.panel.GetClientSizeTuple()
        if x < v:
            self.new.Move((v,-1))
        if y < w:
            self.new.Move((-1,w))
        if x+200 > v+s:
            self.new.Move((v+s-200,-1))
        if y+200 > w+t:
            self.new.Move((-1,w+t-200))    

class NewWindow(wx.MiniFrame):

    def __init__(self,MainWindow,id):
        wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self, MainWindow, id, 'New Window', size=(200,200),\
                              style = wx.MINIMIZE | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.CenterOnParent()


if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is AUI. I personally recommend the wx.lib.agw.aui set rather than wx.aui as the former is pure Python and has had a LOT more recent work done on it. There are multiple examples in the wxPython demo package. You can also read about it here:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.aui.framemanager.AuiManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much Mike, exactly what I needed.

With wxpython I found This way:
the child stays in the panel area and it follows the window parent when moving.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Python Test App',size=(600,400))
        self.new = None
        #Widgets
        self.position = (0,0)
        panel_gch = wx.Panel(self,-1,size = (150,-1))
        panel_gch.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(300,400))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour((200,230,200))
        panel_drt = wx.Panel(self,-1,size = (150,-1))
        panel_drt.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.SetSizer(box)

        #Add
        box.Add(panel_gch,0,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.panel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(panel_drt,0,wx.EXPAND)

        #Menu
        status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu=wx.Menu()
        ID_FILE_NEW = 1
        file_menu.Append(ID_FILE_NEW,"New Window","This is a new window")
        menubar.Append(file_menu,"File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        #bind and layout
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.get_new_window)

        panel_gch.Layout()
        self.panel.Layout()
        panel_drt.Layout()
        self.Layout()

    def get_new_window(self,event): # create new window
        if self.new == None:
            self.win_one_move = False
            self.new = NewWindow(self.panel,-1)
            self.new.Show(True)
            self.new.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE,self.window2_on_move)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE,self.window1_on_move)
            v,w =self.GetPosition()
            x, y = self.new.GetPosition()                
            self.get_windows_position((x-v),(y-w))       


    def get_windows_position(self,x,y):
        self.position = (x,y)
        print "check",self.position

    def window2_on_move(self,event): # Window2 must stay in
        if self.win_one_move == False:
            x, y = event.GetPosition()
            v,w =self.panel.GetScreenPosition()
            s,t = self.panel.GetClientSizeTuple()
            new_x,new_y = self.new.GetClientSizeTuple()
            if x < v:
                self.new.Move((v,-1))
            if y < w:
                self.new.Move((-1,w))
            if x+new_x > v+s:
                self.new.Move((v+s-new_x,-1))
            if y+new_y > w+t:
                self.new.Move((-1,w+t-new_y))
            v,w =self.GetPosition()
            x,y = self.new.GetPosition() 
            self.get_windows_position((x-v),(y-w))
        if self.win_one_move == True:

            self.win_one_move = False

    def window1_on_move(self,event):
        self.win_one_move = True
        print "1 move"
        x,y = self.GetPosition()
        self.new.Move((x+self.position[0],y+self.position[1]))        
        print self.position


class NewWindow(wx.MiniFrame):

    def __init__(self,MainWindow,id):
        wx.MiniFrame.__init__(self, MainWindow, id, 'New Window', size=(200,200),\
                              style = wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.CenterOnParent()


if __name__=='__main__':
        app=wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Can be use by another.Thanks